# The integral of mollifier function is $1 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

\begin{eqnarray}
u(x) = 
\begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}}& \text{ if } \|x\| < 1\\
                 0& \text{ if } \|x\|\geq 1
                 \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
 I am trying to show the integral of the  mollifier function $u$ equals $1$. Help please. Thank you.

Comment: If you look up 'mollifier' in wikipedia you'll find this function with a normalizing factor $1/I_n$ as an example. The integral of your function is not $=1$, but you can just divide it by it's own integral to acchieve this.

Comment: but i could not find  it 1 by dividing its integral. Can you explain How to solve the integral ? Since they are same it equals 1 ?

Comment: $\int \frac{|f(x)|}{\int |f(y)|dy }dx= \frac{\int |f(x)|dx}{\int |f(y)|dy}=1$ for every integrable function (the integral of which is nonzero). You don't need to show the integral of your function is $=1$ (and I doubt it is), you just need to normalize it.