# The integral of the standard mollifier function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Firstly, I would like to say that I know that it was asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160811/the-integral-of-mollifier-function-is-1), but the question wasn't answered. I'm self studying PDE by Evans's book and I'm trying understand why the integral of a mollifier is $1$. I will put the definition of a mollifier below according Evans's book.

> $\textbf{Definition:}$
>
> Let $\eta: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>
> $\eta(x) := \begin{cases}
> C \exp \left( \frac{1}{|x|^2 - 1} \right) \hspace{1.0cm} \text{if} \ |x| < 1\\
> 0 \hspace{3.6cm} \text{if} \ |x| \geq 1,
> \end{cases}$
>
> the constant $C > 0$ selected so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta \ dx = 1$.
>
> The function $\eta$ is called $\textit{the standard mollifier}$.

I'll be gratefull if someone can tells me how can I compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta \ dx$.

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\eta dx = 1$ because of the choice of $C$.

Comment: Yes, but my doubt it's how can I compute $A := \int_{B(0, 1)} \exp{\left( \frac{1}{|x|^2 - 1} \right)} \ dx$?I know that it's just take $C := \frac{1}{A}$ to have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta \ dx = 1$

Comment: I'm curious why you need to know the exact value of $C$. I've never found a reason to know an exact value of $C$.

Comment: You can compute it numerically with a computer, but as @DisintegratingByParts said, there is never any reason to know what $A$ is. Maybe it is a misunderstanding of language; you are allowed to define $C:=1/A$ even if you do not know the value of $A$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, it's just a curiosity. I thought that if is possible normalize $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta \ dx$ choosing $C := \frac{1}{A}$, then I would be able to compute the value of $A$.

Comment: Now answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4359683).